# Android ArrayAdapter crashing when inserting

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

The application crashes when inserting data from the database in an `autoCompleteTextView`.

I have 2 classes

First, Test class

```
public class Test extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    final DataBaseHelper myDb = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    final String [] myData = myDb.SelectAllData();
    final AutoCompleteTextView autoCom = findViewById(R.id.stations);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, myData);
    autoCom.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}}
```

Second, DataBaseHelper class

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "stations";
private static final String TABLE_STATIONS = "stations";

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

public String[] SelectAllData() {
    try {
        String arrData[] = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String strSQL = "SELECT name FROM " + TABLE_STATIONS;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(strSQL, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                arrData = new String[cursor.getCount()];
                int i = 0;
                do {
                    arrData[i] = cursor.getString(0);
                    i++;
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return arrData;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace if you can, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

## The Issue

I believe that your issue is that you will encounter a ***table not found*** error as the database contains no tables. However, your are trapping the exception and taking no action as such the App will appear to not work.

If you were to add

`e.printStackTrace();`

before **`return null`** then the log would include something similar :-

```
2020-01-10 11:32:17.856 E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: stations
2020-01-10 11:32:17.856 W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: stations (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT name FROM stations
2020-01-10 11:32:17.859 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
2020-01-10 11:32:17.859 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:986)
2020-01-10 11:32:17.859 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:593)
2020-01-10 11:32:17.859 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
2020-01-10 11:32:17.860 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
2020-01-10 11:32:17.860 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
2020-01-10 11:32:17.860 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
2020-01-10 11:32:17.860 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1443)
2020-01-10 11:32:17.860 W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1382)
2020-01-10 11:32:17.860 W/System.err:     at a.so59673151notable.DataBaseHelper.SelectAllData(DataBaseHelper.java:27)
2020-01-10 11:32:17.860 W/System.err:     at a.so59673151notable.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
```

- It is not a good idea to trap SQLite Exceptions as they will, in general, be serious errors and as can be seen from your own experience, confusing as you believe that the issue lie with the Array not being built.

## The Fix

### Part 1

You should use the **onCreate** method, of the **DataBaseHelper** class to create the **stations** table.

e.g.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_STATIONS + "(name TEXT);");
}
```

- of course that may well not be the schema that you require, it is purely an example. You may wish to refer to [CREATE TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

### Part 2

As the database has been created, the DataBaseHelper's **onCreate** method will not run, as it only runs one when the database is created. As such you need to delete the database. When developing the easiest ways to do this is to either :-

1. Delete/Clear the App's data
2. Uninstall the App

After which you can then rerun the App.

## More

To get data from the database you need to add the data to the database, as such you'd want to add a method to the DataBaseHelper class along the lines of (again the assumption is of the basic table created above) :-

```
public long insertStation(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("name",name);
    return db.insert(TABLE_STATIONS,null,cv);
}
```

You may wish to have a read of [insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

You could then have something like the following in the **Test** class :-

```
final DataBaseHelper myDb = new DataBaseHelper(this); //<<<<< EXISTING LINE
myDb.insertStation("MyFirstStation");
myDb.insertStation("MySecondStation");
final String [] myData = myDb.SelectAllData(); //<<<<< EXISTING LINE
```

- Note this is just for testing, it will add the same data each time the App is run, so for each run there will be 2 extra rows.

## Testing

The above changes have been tested by using :-

```
    final DataBaseHelper myDb = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    myDb.insertStation("MyFirstStation");
    myDb.insertStation("MySecondStation");
    final String [] myData = myDb.SelectAllData();
    for (String s: myData) {
        Log.d("STATIONINFO","Station Name is " + s);
    }
```

This results in (for the first run after installing the App) :-

> ```
> 2020-01-10 11:49:42.321 D/STATIONINFO: Station Name is MyFirstStation
> 2020-01-10 11:49:42.321 D/STATIONINFO: Station Name is MySecondStation
> ```